# impossible to unBind from a remote service

Tags: android, android-service

I'm working on an application that uses a remote servicer for some communication and processing tasks. The application is working good but i'm having some problems for unbind from the server that are making the app unstable. The architecture of the app is as follow:

See picture here:
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8aFlQkvXrcqbEFhSnRpVzJab3M

As you can see, I create and object of a class called Device where I start the service HealthService and then this service start another service. The communication between the Device and HealthService is with AIDL. The communication between HealthService and BluetoothService is with Message.

The communication works fine and then I got the data. But when I want to close this channel of communication for allow other devices to bind later, bind doesnt work. It means all devices I create are listening and working with the data even I have unbinded then. It is causing many conflicts that I would like to solve.

Here you have some code:

Device (binding healthservice):

```
        intent= new Intent("com.signove.health.service.HealthService");
    context.startService(intent);
    context.bindService(intent, serviceConnection, 0);
```

Device (unbinding healthservice):

```
    context.unbindService(serviceConnection);
    Log.w("kill", "Device: Service connection unbinded");
    Log.w("kill", "Device: Binded = " + Boolean.toString(api.asBinder().isBinderAlive()));
```

isBinderAlive always returns true...

I have tried to destroy the service with stopService but this causes a crash. On the services onUnbind is acceded. I have implemented that when onUnbind is called the services makes unBind from the other service for cleaning everything up, but it keeps crashing.

Someone can help me? :). Ask more information if needed.

Comment: I am having the same problem - ServiceConnection#onServiceConnected is called when I bind, but when I unbind ServiceConnection#onServiceDisconnected is never called.